# PHP OOP - Accessing property value is returning empty

Tags: php, oop

I have the following class, and for some reason it's not accessing the `test` property. Why is this? I'm new to OOP, so please be easy on me. Thanks

```
class Test {
    private $test;

    function __contruct() {
        $this->test = "test";
    }

    static function test() {
        echo $this->test;
    }
}

$test = new Test;
$test::test();
```

Comment: By those edits that you've made (removing the static keyword on the `test()` method and the associated changes) the concept differed completely, It's now a no problem question !!!

Comment: It's still not echoing anything

Comment: I thought it's a typo, but you need to change the `__contruct()` to `__construct()`.

Comment: By the way, I'd say that it was generally bad form to edit the question in such a way that the answers now make no sense.

Comment: @TheGeneral I agree, and mightyspaj3, you should edit your question and return the `static` keyword back to its place (before the `function test()` tokens).

Answer (score 3):

> Because static methods are callable without an instance of the object
>   created, the pseudo-variable `$this` is not available inside the method
>   declared as static.

[PHP Documentations](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

Comment: What if it was a public function? That still doesn't work either

Comment: It is independent of visibility, also take a look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

Comment: I don't understand, I just want to know why I can't echo $this->this

Comment: If you instantiate a class, you create an object. the `$this` refers to object; now, static methods are available without the existence of even one object, so, simply you cannot access `$this` in static methods :)

Answer (score 0):

Good morning.
It seems you have 3 issues with your code.

1. There is a syntax error at constructor line change it from `__contruct` to `__construct`.
2. Change test function visibility to `public`
3. Access your function with the `->` instead of `::`

Comment: The second item, the visibility issue!, has nothing to do with the concept of static methods!

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate further on the above answers: Static methods and variables are not linked to any particular instance of the object, this is why you have to call test with `$test::test()`. This also means that you cannot access an instance variable from without a static method and it doesn't really make sense to do so (If you had multiple instances of the object with different values set for that variable, how would the interpreter know which instance/value to use?)

If you want to have a field accessible from a static method then you have to make the field static as well. So, if you wanted to have `$test` accessible from your static method `test()` then you'd have to write your function as something along these lines:

```
class Test {
    private static $test;

    function __contruct() {
        Test::$test = "test";
    }

    public function test() {
        echo Test::$test;
    }
}

$test = new Test;
$test::test();
```

However, it doesn't really make sense to be initialising a static field like that in your constructor. So you'd more likely be wanting to do something like:

```
class Test {
    private static $test = "test";

    function __contruct() {
    }

    public static function test() {
        echo Test::$test;
    }
}

$test = new Test;
$test::test();
```

Or, if you don't actually require test() to be static then you could just make it an instance method:

```
class Test {
    private $test = "test";

    function __contruct() {
        $this->$test = "test"
    }

    public function test() {
        echo $this->$test;
    }
}

$test = new Test;
$test->test();
```